# The applet is not showing

Tags: java, applet, awt, jcreator

When I run this applet it does not show anything. What is the problem in this code? Did I miss anything? Thanks for your help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Pucca extends Applet {

public void init() {
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Color yellow = new Color(255, 255, 51);
    g.setColor(yellow);
    g.fillRect(500,50,400,400);

    Color white = new Color(255,255,255);
    g.setColor(white);
    g.fillOval(600, 100, 125, 125);

}
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: I can see the applet now. I just don't click the maaximize button. Thanks for your concern! Hey can you see my other question regarding how to move an applet in jcreator? Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: *"can you see my other question.."* I'll consider that once you've answered my two questions. They weren't rhetorical questions..

Comment: What's your two questions?

Comment: The two sentences ending with '?'. If you cannot figure it out, I suggest a different career than programming..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do. In general, when you override a method in a sub-class, you call the overridden method in the base class (not always, though). So, add the following line at the beginning of your "paint" method:

```
super.paint(g);
```

This is important for the proper painting of the applet.

Comment: Where can I add the super.paint(g);? I add it before the Color statement but nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, just before the yellow color line. If nothing happens, maybe you have an error in the way you add the applet to the web page or in using the applet viewer. You don't show it in your question. Anyway, the "super.paint(g)" is very important, or else the applet will not be painted correctly.

Comment: I can see the applet now! Thanks!

Comment: *"`super.paint(g);` This is important for the proper painting of the applet."* It's also important for any custom painting in ***any*** AWT **or** Swing component (though with Swing components, we more often override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method). And while that may not have been the answer to this problem, it is certainly true, and worth noting.

Comment: @CherryLugtu If the answer solved your problem then please mark it as the correct answer. All questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to be useful to future visitors too. Please give this question a correct answer.